# Search in mongodb with or without form values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my mongoose model:

```
{
    id : Schema.ObjectId,
    subjectCode: String,
    part: String,
    paper : [{
        year: Number,
        month: String
    }],
    question: String,
    questionNumber: String,
    marks: Number
}
```

I want to make an advanced search using this model.
The search form has these html input fields.

```
<input type="text" name="subjectCode">
<input type="text" name="part">
<select name="year" multiple>
    <option value="">Any</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>
<select name="month" multiple>
    <option value="">Any</option>
    <option value="JAN">JAN</option>
    <option value="FEB">FEB</option>
    <option value="MAR">MAR</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="question">
<input type="text" name="questionNumber">
<input type="text" name="marks">
```

Mongoose query I wrote for the search:

```
Question.find({
    subjectCode: req.query.subjectName, 
    'paper.year': req.query.year, 
    'paper.month': req.query.month,
    part: req.query.questionPart,
    questionNumber: req.query.questionsNumber}, function(err, question){
        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }
        else{
            res.json(question);
        }
});
```

The problem now is, when any one or more fields is missing/omitted in the get request, this query is not working.
I need a mongoose query for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally set your query conditions, like:

```
var conditions = {};
if(req.query.subjectName !== undefined) conditions.subjectCode = req.query.subjectName;
....
Question.find(conditions, function(err, question){...});
```

Comment: Thanks Hank.
That almost fixes everything.